Sec-Fetch-Dest request header attribute to determine if it is a page
I need to process redirections in my website, but only for pages and not for other files like images, stylesheets, etc.
For example, requests like https://example-mysite.com/* should be redirected to https://example-site-two.com/*
Requests like https://example-mysite.com/assets/app.css should not be redirected.
So, the code logic is checking for the Sec-Fetch-Dest attribute and if its value is document. If this is satisfied, then the redirection happens.
However, on logging I see that for many valid page requests, the Sec-Fetch-Dest attribute is either empty or unavailable.
NameValueCollection nvcReqHeaders = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers;
foreach (string key in nvcReqHeaders.AllKeys)
{
   Log.AppendLine(key + " : " + nvcReqHeaders[key]);
}

Can you please suggest if there is a better logic to determine only pages, apart from filtering out by known relative paths like /assets, /images. Because here too there are lot of unknown asset paths from the default framework itself and a redirection could impact that.
Thank you

Are you sure you receive HTML requests without Sec-Fetch-Dest set to "document"? This is pretty bizarre. I checked all the possible places I could Imagine and didn't find document requests without this header. Since Sec-* headers are standard It's hard to believe that modern browsers don't use it in appropriate cases. Check twice or show request log
